# Dojo: Get ID of inlineEditBox on OnChange

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using dojo and dijit and have an inlineEditBox widget.  I'm trying to capture the onchange event and send a key/value post to a php page (to set into a database).  The value is the new value just submitted, available from e.target.value.  That's easy.

I'd like the key value to be the id of the inlineEditBox widget.  How can I access that programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since InlineEditBox is a widget it's best not to monitor DOM level events.   Instead, why not connect to InlineEditBox.onChange?   For example:

```
<span dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" ...>
     <script type="dojo/connect" event="onChange" args="value">
          console.log(this.id + " changed to value" + value);
     </script>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span data-dojo-type="dijit.InlineEditBox" data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){ applyChange(arguments[0]);}" width="70px" title="Admin Notes">Database Value</span>
<script>
function applyChange(newValue){
    console.log(newValue);
}
</script>
```